# Ambiguity about the C ++ standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

According to this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct T {
    T() { cout << "default"<<endl; }
    T(string s) { cout << "ctor "<< endl; }
    T(const T& t) { cout << "copy ctor"<< endl; }
};
int main()
{
    T x = T(T(T()));
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
default
```

and according to [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17):

> (17) The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination
> type is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the
> source type is the type of the initializer expression. If the
> initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the
> source type is not defined.
>
> .....
>
> (17.6.1) If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the
> cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
> class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
> initialize the destination object. [Example: T x = T(T(T())); calls
> the T default constructor to initialize x. — end example]

it gives the same result in c ++ 11 (GNU GCC v7.1.1)

First question:
Is the source type defined in this statement?

```
T x = T(T(T()));
```

Now if we add this function to this code :

```
string f(T t) {return "str";}
```

and replacement `T x = T(T(f(T())));` for `T x = T(T(T()));`

output :

```
default
ctor
```

now is the source type defined?

isn't `T()` initializer expression?

if yes According to the standard, the default constructor should be called, but why is the `T(string s)` called for x?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the source type defined in this statement?
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(T()));
> ```

Yes, because `T(T(T()))` is a single expression; it can be paranthesized as in this case.

The same reasoning applies for

```
T(T(f(T())))
```

since this is a single expression as well.

---

> isn't T() initializer expression?

In general, sure, but not in the above cases. The entire expression between `=` and `;` is the initializer expression.

---

> but why is the T(string s) called for x?

Because there is an explicit call to `f` which returns a `string`, and that argument is used to construct a `T`, which calls the `string` constructor.

```
T x = T(  T(f(  T()  ))  );
             // ^^^      calls the default constructor
       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  calls the string constructor
```

Comment: I was a little confused
What is the exact meaning of initializer expression in the standard? What is the standard meaning of this word? the most external T()? most internal T()?(
About when we have a function)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the *initializer-expression* is the expression between the `=` and the `;`, or in other words the `...` in a declaration like `T t = ... ;`

Comment: ok, but according to the standard that says **the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object.** And according to you, **the initializer-expression is the expression between the `=` and the `;`** That is, The most external T(), So why not call the copy-ctor(When it is like this: `T t = T(T(T()))` )?

Comment: That syntax is [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Despite the name there is no copy constructor invoked, and copy-elision will take care of the "temporary" `T`s.

Comment: Can explain more about `is used`. what this `is used` means in the standard? Does it mean calling a function?

Comment: Depends on the context. I'm not sure which `is used` usage you're referring to.